# Brachial plexus compression: What to do and what to avoid?

Tags: exercise, workout, injury

I got diagnosed with brachial plexus compression (basically the pectoralis compresses the nerves going to the arm at the brachial plexus, which entraps them at that point). Unfortunatly the only thing the doc could say, was to take it easy when working out and wait. It'll go away on itself over time.

Are there any exercises I should avoid at all now? What can I do to easy the situation?

Answer (score 1):

[Brachial plexus compression](https://now.aapmr.org/compressive-entrapment/), [pectoralis minor syndrome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5617946/) and [thoracic outlet syndrome](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/thoracic-outlet-syndrome/symptoms-causes/syc-20353988) are three names for the same condition (these and other names may apply, depending on the cause).

Beside pectoral minor muscle, there may be other causes, such as cervical rib, tumors, etc. So, it is good to ask a doctor what is the actual cause.

In general, excessive use of arms, especially lifting the arms above the shoulder level, and carrying heavy backpacks is discouraged. An orthopedist or physiotherapist can tell you if any exercises can help. It's not possible to recommend any specific exercises here because they can differ a lot from case to case.

There is more specific information in the linked and other articles.